# CSS - change div's display from grid to flexbox with media queries

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a div that is a css grid container. When the page width drops below a certain size, I would like all elements of the grid to be placed on a line. I think you should be able to change the display type to flex box, I tried doing this and the grid stays the same. Here is the code I am using:

See the Pen [NYjOmL](https://codepen.io/MeaningOf42/pen/NYjOmL/) by biltimi@gmail.com ([@MeaningOf42](https://codepen.io/MeaningOf42)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

```
/* The important part of the CSS*/

@media (max-width: 40em) {
    .image {
        visibility:hidden;
    }

    .grid-container {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
}

/* The Styling of the container class: */
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 16.6% 16.6% 33% 16% 16%;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 3fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      ". . Image . ."
      "blog bikes Image about links"
      "shop events Image contact team"
      ". . Image . ."
}
```

For context, I am trying to replicate deaf pigeon's website ( http://www.deafpigeon.co.uk) using as close to pure vanilla HTML and CSS to practice laying out pages. I want my div to do the same thing as the deaf pigeon navigation bar.

Does anyone have solutions? I might be going about this the wrong way if so be sure to let me know.

Comment: media queries should go after the original rule so that they override them

Answer (score 1):

As Pete said, your media query needs to follow your base rules in order to override when the condition is met. The preferred approach would be to declare your mobile styles first followed by a desktop override in your media query.

```
.grid-container {
    display: inline-flex;
}
@media all and (min-width: 40em) {
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
    }
}
```

Notice the change from max-width to min-width to ensure that this override kicks in when the viewport is larger than 40em

Answer (score -1):

Just move your media query declaration to the end of the file. The media query rule you defined is getting executed but it is getting overwritten by the `.grid-container` rule that comes after it.

Comment: Just wanted to include all that could be done. Edited.